# How to get last data and set a color in map foreach in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const pages = ["main", "about", "contact"];
const pagesList = pages.map((page) => <li>{page}</li>);
```

Result:

```html
<ul>
<li>Main</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

i want to set "a" tag to "Main and About" "li". How can i do that? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd probaby replace the strings in the array with objects. Each object would have `text` and `color` property. Then in the mapping function I'd use both the properties for creating the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use map, you can try this

```
const pages = ["main", "about", "contact"];
let currentIndex = 0;
const pagesList = pages.map((page) => 
{
  currentIndex === pages.length - 1 ? <li>{page}</li> : <li a>{page}</li> 
  currentIndex++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to everyone who helped me. I solved my problem**
i was trying to this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href='/test'>Home</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href='/test'>test1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href='/test'>test2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href='/test'>test3</a>
 </li>
 <li>test4</li>
</ul>
```

every li elements has "a" element but last li not have "a" element i tried to do this.
my pageHeader.js component its like this

`import React from "react";`

`import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`

```
export const PageHeader = (props) => {
 const pages = props.pages;
 const pagesList = pages.map((page) => (
  <>
  {page == pages[pages.length - 1] ? (
    <li>{page}</li>
  ) : (
    <li>
      <Link to='test'>{page}</Link>
    </li>
  )}
</>
));
return (
 <>
  <div className='pageHeader'>
    <ul>{pagesList}</ul>
  </div>
</>
);
};
```

I find the last data with javascript length expression;
I added element "a" with "if" "else" statements.
then i called this component in my work place like this:

```
<PageHeader pages={["Home", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]} />
```

Answer (score -1):

you can solve this by CSS only

```css
ul.parent>*:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li>Main</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but i give an easy example to solve my problem. The problem is not color. I want to add <a> tag to first and second li but not last li